# Rails order posts by attributes from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting

So I have a social-bookmarking-esque setup here. 4 tables: posts, users, comments, and votes. The homepage simply points to the posts model's index page and runs a loop over the `Post.all` array and displays some basic info: `title`, `upvotes` - `downvotes` (I call ti the post's "score").

Now what I need to do it order these posts in (i'm guessing) the model by their score divided by their relative creation time (how many seconds since page load was this post created?). Rails gives me a `created_at` column in my posts object and I have a table of votes which looks like this:

## Posts model

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible  :id, :title, :url, :user_id, :comment_count, :agreement
  has_many :votes
  has_many :comments
  belongs_to :user
end
```

## Votes model

```
class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :direction, :post_id, :vote_type, :user_id
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :comment
end
```

IDs in the post model correspond with post_id's in the vote model.

`:direction` is a boolean. `0` associated with up voting and `1` associated with downvoting. Post_ID is the ID of the post the vote was cast on.

**How should I order the posts so that their position on the homepage is determined by both their creation time AND their up votes - down votes?**

```
def index
    @posts = Post.join(:votes).order(<???>)
end
```

ETA: @shweta is on the right track with joining the posts and votes tables. The select portion of his answer does not work, however.

Comment: there should be belongs_to :user 
belongs_to :post
belongs_to :comment
# singular not plural

Comment: If I do that it breaks the :user attribute coming from the database. That's a different bug, any ideas there?

Comment: @shweta Fixed this by renaming the user column in the posts model to user_id.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** I don't know ruby or rails, only SQL.

shweta's answer seems really close so I will attempt to finish it with some SQL hack and slash:

order by upvotes and then created_at

```
@posts = Post.joins(:votes).select("posts.id,sum(if(direction = 0, 1, -1)) as score,posts.created_at,OTHER_ATTRS_YOU_NEED").group("posts.id").order("score DESC,posts.created_at")
```

Also, to include posts with zero votes you will need to do a left join:

```
@posts = Post.joins("LEFT JOIN votes ON posts.id = votes.post_id").select("posts.id,sum(if(direction = 0, 1, -1)) as score,posts.created_at,OTHER_ATTRS_YOU_NEED").group("posts.id").order("score DESC,posts.created_at")
```

**Update:** to fix the ordering for un-voted posts:

```
@posts = Post.joins("LEFT JOIN votes ON posts.id = votes.post_id").select("posts.id,sum(if(direction = 0, 1, if(direction is null, 0, -1))) as score,posts.created_at,OTHER_ATTRS_YOU_NEED").group("posts.id").order("score DESC,posts.created_at")
```

**Update 2:** improved ranking

If you exclude older items you might end up with an empty list (eg on quiet days), which is probably not what you want. You might be better off adding another column for ranking, something like this:

```
@posts = Post.joins("LEFT JOIN votes ON posts.id = votes.post_id").select(
    "posts.id," +
    "sum(if(direction = 0, 1, if(direction is null, 0, -1))) as score," +
    "(sum(if(direction = 0, 1, if(direction is null, 0, -1))) * " +
    " if(unix_timestamp() - unix_timestamp(posts.created_at) < 7200, 3, 1)) as rank," +
    "posts.created_at,OTHER_ATTRS_YOU_NEED"
).group("posts.id").order("rank DESC,posts.created_at")
```

For ranking purposes, this triples the score of posts less than 2 hours old.

Comment: Wow, this almost works! The only problem is that the LEFT JOIN one orders posts with negative votes above ones with no votes. How can I include ones without votes, keep those above ones with negative votes?

Comment: Thank you so much! It works great! Can I exclude things that are too old? I'm going for a Reddit-like algorithm. If something is new and has lots of votes, make it #1. But exclude things that are a few hours old if newer content comes in.

Comment: Updated post with a suggested solution

Comment: Sweet! Wow, thanks man! Do I just add another column to the database for rankings and make sure it's referenced in the model?

Comment: There's no need to change your database, the column is computed at query time using the code in my answer. The ranking column doesn't need to be included in your model since it's just for sorting inside the database, but if you add it to your model I think you'll be able to retrieve it.

Comment: Hmmm... when I employ your latest update, it seems to have no effect. If I submit something brand new it starts at the bottom of the list.

Comment: Hmm yes that will happen because it has no votes yet. Its ranking score will be 0 until it gets some more votes. You might need to find some more clever way of calculating the rank. Instead of `if(unix_timestamp() - unix_timestamp(posts.created_at) < 7200, 3, 1))` you could go with `max(7200 - unix_timestamp() + unix_timestamp(posts.created_at), 1)`, this should roughly order new posts (<2hrs) by time then order old posts at/near the bottom by their score.

Comment: Oops there's a mistake in that last comment: `greatest(7200 - unix_timestamp() + unix_timestamp(posts.created_at), 1)`

Comment: Wow, you are extraordinary with SQL. Thank you kindly!

Comment: Could you look at a bug quick? It multiplies the post's score even if it's negative. So if it has negative votes, it will have a WORSE score if it's new. If the post's score is negative, it should divide the score if it's a recent one, and when it;s positive it should multiply it. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: wrap it in `abs()`, like `abs(sum(if(direction = 0, 1, if(direction is null, 0, -1))))`

Answer (score 1):

order by upvotes and then created_at

```
@posts = Post.joins(:votes).select("posts.id,count(votes.id) AS vote_count,posts.created_at,OTHER_ATTRS_YOU_NEED").group("posts.id").order("vote_count DESC,posts.created_at")
```

order by created_at and then upvotes

```
@posts = Post.joins(:votes).select("posts.id,count(votes.id) AS vote_count,posts.created_at,OTHER_ATTRS_YOU_NEED").group("posts.id").order("posts.created_at, vote_count DESC")
```

Comment: I don't have a vote_count column, only a votes table with rows of votes.

Comment: Okay, then I get `Mysql2::Error: Column 'created_at' in field list is ambiguous` ...any ideas?

Comment: Here's what I have: `Post.joins(:votes).select("posts.id,count(votes.id) AS vote_count,url,title,user,created_at").group("posts.id").order("vote_count DESC,posts.created_at")`

Comment: All this seems to do it exclude items with no votes, it does not re-arrange the array.

Comment: I think the problem is that this supposedly join `:votes`, but the votes are calculated by up votes - down votes. Can you re-look at this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to order by `rating/(time elapsed since creation)`. It could be done in pure Ruby with sort_by but isn't as efficient as raw sql.

So... doing it on the DB requires calculating Times elpased since Post#creation. On Mysql you have [TIMEDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff) (on Postres/Oracle/etc it might be different) for that sort of calculation. The SQL would more or less include (in light/pseudo code) :

```
class Post
  def self.order_by_popularity
    score        = "sum(if(direction = 0, 1, -1)) as score"
    votes_count  = "count(votes.id) as votes_count"
    time_elapsed = "ABS(Timediff(#{Time.now}, created_at)) as time_elapsed"

    select("posts.*, votes.id, #{score}, #{votes_count}, #{time_elapsed}").
    join(:votes).group("votes.id").
    order "ABS(votes_count/time_elapsed)"
  end
end
```

UPDATE : Assembling all the suggestions you get the above (BTW join(:votes) is a left join by default). I wonder if there are any gotchas....

Where vote_count would come from a caching column on Posts or a join+group thingy as previous comments suggest.

Side note : I succesfully used this type of query so I hopefully pointed you in the right direction, but frankly this probably needs more test/trial than what the typical stackoverflow help provides.

Comment: Thanks for a new direction to go in! I'll experiment with this.

Comment: Where is votes_count being defined though? I get how timediff works, but how does votes_count work?

Comment: a regular/magic rails attribute on posts or `select("posts.*, count(votes.id) as vote_count").joins(:votes)`

Comment: Just add the column 'votes_count' to your your posts table. `belongs_to :post, :counter_cahe => true`. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html